# What do the @ (at symbols) in a terminfo manipulation code mean?

Tags: tty, emacs24, xterm, iterm2, terminfo

I'm trying to convert a terminfo string from xterm to something that will work with iTerm2 in order to [get 24bit colors working in emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32506/conditional-true-color-24-bit-color-support-for-iterm2-and-terminal-app-in-osx?noredirect=1#comment50112_32506). The investigating and research I've done so far leads me to believe that the terminfo manipulation codes I'm using to set stf24/setb24 are being incorrectly interpreted by iTerm2, so I want to understand what these are doing.

Here are the custom values that emacs requires:

```
xterm-24bit|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode,
   use=xterm-256color,
   setb24=\E[48:2:%p1%@{65536@}%/%d:%p1%@{256@}%/%@{255@}%&%d:%p1%@{255@}%&%dm,
   setf24=\E[38:2:%p1%@{65536@}%/%d:%p1%@{256@}%/%@{255@}%&%d:%p1%@{255@}%&%dm,
# Use semicolon separators.
xterm-24bits|xterm with 24-bit direct color mode,
   use=xterm-256color,
   setb24=\E[48;2;%p1%@{65536@}%/%d;%p1%@{256@}%/%@{255@}%&%d;%p1%@{255@}%&%dm,
   setf24=\E[38;2;%p1%@{65536@}%/%d;%p1%@{256@}%/%@{255@}%&%d;%p1%@{255@}%&%dm,
```

I know that the first bit e.g. `\e[48:2:` is the escape code specifying the colour location (in this case background) and the colour format (2 means full 24-bit RGB format requiring 3 control segments).
Looking at this documentation ['Supported TERMINFO Manipulation Codes'](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GVTT_termdef) I know that it is taking a parameter '1' from the stack with `%p1`, and performing a few other operations on this (`%/ - division, %& - AND`) but I'm not sure what `%@` means or what the numbers in brackets mean `%@{65536}`, and also what the `%dm` does at the end. Can anyone assist?

Overall, I believe emacs only passes the one parameter (presumably a single number within 256^3 0-16,777,216), so I think this is somehow breaking it apart into the 3 constituent RGB colours that the terminal needs, but I haven't quite worked out how, and then whether there is an incompatibility and where it lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`@`** marks are not part of the *terminfo* description; they are used in the original [texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/index.html) file to prevent the curly braces from being interpreted.  What you're reading is cut/paste from someone who didn't understand either part of the markup...

Without the **`@`** marks, you'll have constants, e.g., `%{65536}` used in arithmetic.

The "%dm on the end" is just the third parameter, i.e., the blue value in RGB (note that there are two other "%d" marks), with the final character "m".

Comment: "What you're reading is cut/paste from someone who didn't understand either part of the markup..." - That'd be me then! Never touched textinfo files before. Thanks for the assistance, Thomas.